# How can I improve the performance of a feedforward network as a q-value function approximator?

Tags: neural-network, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, feed-forward

I'm trying to navigate an agent in a n*n gridworld domain by using Q-Learning + a feedforward neural network as a q-function approximator. Basically the agent should find the best/shortest way to reach a certain terminal goal position (+10 reward). Every step the agent takes it gets -1 reward. In the gridworld there are also some positions the agent should avoid (-10 reward, terminal states,too).

So far I implemented a Q-learning algorithm, that saves all Q-values in a Q-table and the agent performs well. 
In the next step, I want to replace the Q-table by a neural network, trained online after every step of the agent. I tried a feedforward NN with one hidden layer and four outputs, representing the Q-values for the possible actions in the gridworld (north,south,east, west). 
As input I used a nxn zero-matrix, that has a "1" at the current positions of the agent.

To reach my goal I tried to solve the problem from the ground up:

1. Explore the gridworld with standard Q-Learning and use the Q-map as training data for the Network once Q-Learning is finished
   --> worked fine
2. Use Q-Learning and provide the updates of the Q-map as trainingdata
   for NN (batchSize = 1)
   --> worked good
3. Replacy the Q-Map completely by the NN. (This is the point, when it gets interesting!)

   -> FIRST MAP: 4 x 4
   As described above, I have 16 "discrete" Inputs, 4 Output and it works fine with 8 neurons(relu) in the hidden layer (learning rate: 0.05). I used a greedy policy with an epsilon, that reduces from 1 to 0.1 within 60 episodes.
   [The test scenario is shown here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMiGv.jpg) Performance is compared beetween standard qlearning with q-map and "neural" qlearning (in this case i used 8 neurons and differnt dropOut rates).

To sum it up: Neural Q-learning works good for small grids, also the performance is okay and reliable.

-> Bigger MAP: 10 x 10

Now I tried to use the neural network for bigger maps.
At first I tried this simple [case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bm58.png).

In my case the neural net looks as following: 100 input; 4 Outputs; about 30 neurons(relu) in one hidden layer; again I used a decreasing exploring factor for greedy policy; over 200 episodes the learning rate decreases from 0.1 to 0.015 to increase stability.

At frist I had problems with convergence and interpolation between single positions caused by the discrete input vector. 
To solve this I added some neighbour positions to the vector with values depending on thier distance to the current position. This improved the learning a lot and the policy got better. Performance with 24 neurons is seen in the picture above.

Summary: the simple case is solved by the network, but only with a lot of parameter tuning (number of neurons, exploration factor, learning rate) and special input transformation.

Now here are my questions/problems I still haven't solved:

(1) My network is able to solve really simple cases and examples in a 10 x 10 map, but it fails as the problem gets a bit more complex. In cases where failing is very likely, the network has no change to find a correct policy.
I'm open minded for any idea that could improve performace in this cases.

(2) Is there a smarter way to transform the input vector for the network? I'm sure that adding the neighboring positons to the input vector on the one hand improve the interpolation of the q-values over the map, but on the other hand makes it harder to train special/important postions to the network. I already tried standard cartesian two-dimensional input (x/y) on an early stage, but failed.

(3) Is there another network type than feedforward network with backpropagation, that generally produces better results with q-function approximation? Have you seen projects, where a FF-nn performs well with bigger maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's known that Q-Learning + a feedforward neural network as a q-function approximator can fail even in simple problems [Boyan & Moore, 1995].

Rich Sutton has a question in the FAQ of his [web site](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/%7Esutton/RL-FAQ.html#backpropagation) related with this.

A possible explanation is the phenomenok known as *interference* described in [Barreto & Anderson, 2008]:

> Interference happens when the update of one state–action pair changes the Q-values of other pairs, possibly in the wrong direction.
>
> Interference is naturally associated with generalization, and also happens in conventional supervised learning. Nevertheless, in the reinforcement learning paradigm its effects tend to be much more harmful. The reason for this is twofold. First, the combination of interference and bootstrapping can easily become unstable, since the updates are no longer strictly local. The convergence proofs for the algorithms derived from (4) and (5) are based on the fact that these operators are contraction mappings, that is, their successive application results in a sequence converging to a fixed point which is the solution for the Bellman equation [14,36]. When using approximators, however, this asymptotic convergence is lost, [...]
>
> Another source of instability is a consequence of the fact that in on-line reinforcement learning the distribution of the incoming data depends on the current policy. Depending on the dynamics of the system, the agent can remain for some time in a region of the state space which is not representative of the entire domain. In this situation, the learning algorithm may allocate excessive resources of the function approximator to represent that region, possibly “forgetting” the previous stored information.
>
> One way to alleviate the interference problem is to use a local function approximator. The more independent each basis function is from each other, the less severe this problem is (in the limit, one has one basis function for each state, which corresponds to the lookup-table case) [86]. A class of local functions that have been widely used for approximation is the radial basis functions (RBFs) [52].

So, in your kind of problem (n*n gridworld), an RBF neural network should produce better results.

**References**

Boyan, J. A. & Moore, A. W. (1995) Generalization in reinforcement learning: Safely approximating the value function. NIPS-7. San Mateo, CA: Morgan Kaufmann.

André da Motta Salles Barreto & Charles W. Anderson (2008) Restricted gradient-descent algorithm for value-function approximation in reinforcement learning, Artificial Intelligence 172 (2008) 454–482

Comment: Thanks for answering my question!
In case I want to transfere the described task from above to a continous state space, is it still practicable to use a RBF neural network? 
Can my agent profit from deep learning technics or deep reinforcement learning?

Comment: Welcome! Yes, of course, in fact, it has no sense to apply a function approximator (MLP, RBF network or whatever) when the number of states is discrete and small. RBF neural network are specially suitable to problems where the dimensionality of the input space is small. In the case of 2D, as your case, it's great because you can plot easily the Q-function (or even the RBF functions: http://imgur.com/knStnKI) and adjust number of basis functions and widths to adequate values.